# Can't enable Python interpreter in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, interpreter

I have a project with two interpreters: 2.7 and 3.6. Recently, we moved to Python 3.7 and i am stuck with adding it.

Firstly, i installed Python 3.7 via Pyenv, created a virtualenv in the project and tried to add it as an interpreter, but PyCharm doesn't seem to chose it.

Secondly, i installed python from the official site, tried both with virtualenv and system interpreter - nothing happens

Other interpreters work fine, including a system's 3.9.

[image: When i click on 3.7,]

Also, i don't see the 3.7 interpreter in the configuration settings:
[image]

Have anyone else faced the same issue?